# My company is a Rackspace Cloud client (provided to us for free) and I'm trying to find some way to set up version control

Tags: php, git, svn, version-control, rackspace-cloud

As the title says, my (small) business is provided a free Rackspace Cloud client account.  We receive a decent amount of traffic but I haven't been able to put together a business case to move to our own server yet.  However, we are developing some complex apps and I'm frustrated with not having the ability to even ssh into the remote server.  Ultimately, I'd like to set up some sort of version control (at this point, I'll take anything, git or otherwise).

I have control over databases, can FTP, set up cron jobs, and perform a few other basic functions.  I can't think of any way to set up git or something similar without ssh access.  A thought went through my mind that maybe some sort of PHP version control exists that I might be able to set up, but I haven't had any luck finding it yet.

Do you guys have any ideas, thoughts, or advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no complete php git client out there. But you can just use ftp for deployment. Have a look at git ftp: https://github.com/resmo/git-ftp

Comment: Thanks.  This looks like a solution I might be able to work with.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for your git repos (or whatever you want to use) to be on your Rackspace server. You can use one of the various hosting services such as GitHub or BitBucket, or you could just stick a cheap computer in the corner of your office and use that.

Comment: So, would the workflow go something like this? 1) edit on local server 2) update repository 3) upload changes to production server.

Comment: Basically, yes. There are various tools around to automate deployment from a repo to testing and production servers.

Comment: Makes perfect sense.  Could these tools deploy based on the criteria from my original question (ie. minimal access).  Thanks again.

Comment: The fancier ones do all seem to need ssh, but simple tools will work with just FTP. I use a Mac FTP client called Transmit for my own (very simple) website--it has a sync feature to upload only files which have changes.